# Xargs command not supports hadoop put command with multiple input files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, xargs

hadoop supports copying multiple local file to hdfs with below command

```
hadoop fs -put localfile1 localfile2 /user/hadoop/hdfsdir
```

We need to copy hundreds of thousands of files, due to memory issues, we want to copy in chuncks using xargs.

But below command give error.

```
echo "localfile1 localfile2" |xargs  -t -I {} hadoop fs -put {} /user/hadoop/hdfsdir
```

It gives `put: unexpected URISyntaxException error`.

Here `localfile1` and `localfile2` are files in my present working directory.

Single file command is working i.e.

```
echo "localfile1" |xargs  -t -I {} hadoop fs -put {} /user/hadoop/hdfsdir
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late, but I came across your question when I tried to do the same thing.

I followed this [tutorial](http://offbytwo.com/2011/06/26/things-you-didnt-know-about-xargs.html) and wrote the following command to upload all texttiles 4 at a time:

```
find . -name '*.textile' -print0 |xargs  -0 -P 4 -I % hadoop fs -put % /user/myName/
```

- -print0: to do a null separated token-list
- -0: so xarg can recognize the null separator
- -n: so that several puts are run in parallel
- -I: so that each token is included into the hadoop fs -put TOKEN_GOES_HERE

I don't think this approach respects folder structures, meaning the folder structure from your local system is not preserved on the cluster.  Also, if you happen to have the file-names in multiple-folders you'll get file already exists.

Comment: There is no -n in this command line.