# How to use hdfs dfs cp with xargs to work around linux argument list limit?

Tags: hdfs, ubuntu-16.04, xargs

I have a lot of files to copy on HDFS and I encounter the maximum argument list limit of the operating system. A work around that currently works is to generate a single command for a single file to process. However, that requires time.

I am trying to work with xargs to get around the argument limit and reduce processing time. But I am not able to make it work.

Here is the current situation.

I echo (because I have read somewhere that echo is not subject to argument limit) the file names and pipe them to xarg.

```
echo "/user/florian_castelain/test/yolo /user/florian_castelain/ignore_dtl" | xargs -I %  hdfs dfs -cp -p % /user/florian_castelain/test/xargs/
```

However this throws:

> cp: `/user/florian_castelain/test/yolo
> /user/florian_castelain/ignore_dtl': No such file or directory

Based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678850/xargs-command-not-supports-hadoop-put-command-with-multiple-input-files), I tried with:

```
echo "/user/florian_castelain/test/yolo" "/user/florian_castelain/ignore_dtl" | xargs -0 -I %  hdfs dfs -cp -p % /user/florian_castelain/test/xargs/
```

Which prints:

> cp: `/user/florian_castelain/test/yolo
> /user/florian_castelain/ignore_dtl

But no file has been copied at all.

How can I use `xarg` combined with the `hdfs dfs -cp` command to handle the copy of multiple files at once ?

- Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.13.0

## Edit 1

With the verbose flag and this config', I have the following output:

```
echo "/user/florian_castelain/test/yolo /user/florian_castelain/ignore_dtl" | xargs -I %  -t  hdfs dfs -cp -p % /user/florian_castelain/test/xargs/
hdfs dfs -cp -p /user/florian_castelain/test/yolo /user/florian_castelain/ignore_dtl /user/florian_castelain/test/xargs/
```

Which throws:

> cp: `/user/florian_castelain/test/yolo
> /user/florian_castelain/ignore_dtl': No such file or directory

While executing this command manually works fine. Why is that ?

## Edit 2

Based on jjo answer, I tried the following:

```
printf "%s\n" /user/florian_castelain/test/yolo /user/florian_castelain/ignore_dtl | xargs -0 -t -I % hdfs dfs -cp -p % /user/florian_castelain/test/xargs/
```

Which prints:

```
hdfs dfs -cp -p /user/florian_castelain/test/yolo
/user/florian_castelain/ignore_dtl
 /user/florian_castelain/test/xargs/
```

And does not copy anything.

So I tried removing new line character before passing to xargs:

```
printf "%s\n" /user/florian_castelain/test/yolo /user/florian_castelain/ignore_dtl | tr -d "\n"  | xargs -0 -t -I % hdfs dfs -cp -p % /user/florian_castelain/test/xargs/
```

Which prints:

```
hdfs dfs -cp -p /user/florian_castelain/test/yolo/user/florian_castelain/ignore_dtl /user/florian_castelain/test/xargs/
```

But nothing is copied as well. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see you're facing is that whitespace in `yolo` , plus xargs slurping stdin entries as *separated by newlines*.

As your files are local, you should leverage `find -0 | xargs -0` as e.g.:

```
find /user/florian_castelain/foo/bar -type f -0 | xargs -0 -I hdfs dfs -cp -p % /some/dst
```

If you still need/want to feed xargs with "whitespace separated filenames", use `printf "%s\n"` instead (which is also a builtin in `bash` as `echo`), so that *each* file will be outputted with a newline between:

```
printf "%s\n" /user/florian_castelain/test/yolo /user/florian_castelain/ignore_dtl | xargs -I %  hdfs dfs -cp -p % /some/dst
```

Comment: I need xargs to handle more than one parameter. Second option launches one command per parameter, so not viable. First option is not viable either, because the parameter list is built from a python script. I updated my question with something  I tried based on your proposal, without success.